# Placing a revolution slider on a wordpress woocommerce store

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, revolution-slider

So I am trying to place a Revolution slider on top of our Wocommerce shop pages, a lot like we already have on all of our other pages bar the shop.

I've provided the screenshots of how it is now and how I'd like it to look.

We're using a custom theme.

I know how to update my .PHP code if I'm pointed to the right file with the right bit of code!

Suggestions most welcome :)

This is what our shop currently looks like:

[image]

This is what our homepage looks like with the revolution slide (mid transition):

[image]

This is how we'd like the shop to look with the revolution slider:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVar6.png]

Comment: Revolution Slider: Documentation 
https://support.vamtam.com/support/solutions/articles/200734-guide-to-revolution-slider

It;s easy to use,  today im already used it,(you should need to follow guidance )

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't specify how to display the slider on the Woocommerce store pages

Comment: you need to activated  first Revolution Slider in your wp

Comment: It is activated in my WP, but it won't show in my Woocommerce store